# How to draw x amount of circles that user deciedes?

Tags: javascript, canvas

just started with useing canvas in javascript. Also new to Javascript in general. But so far its really fun, but having some problems here and there...
So what i want to do is: the user chooses how many circles thats going to be drawn, up to 20max ish. And then the circles gets drawn like this. If user chooses 6 circles:

O 
OO 
OOO;

So far I have created the box where user puts in the number, and the script for drawing out a circle. But cant really figure out the rest.. Ill be thankful for any help! If you want me to send my code I can do that, even though its probably a mess.. xD

Comment: [MDN -> Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: You're definitely going to want to paste code with all the attempts you've tried; This community helps people with specific issues in their attempts. It doesn't write fresh code implementations :)

Comment: Oh, not been here alot. Didn't know.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split the code for the calculation of the basic coordinates from the code for the actual drawing:

- First produce an array of coordinates expressed in number of rows and columns away from the top-left corner: the idea of the triangle shape is that the column number will never be greater than the row number.
- Then apply the radius to that list to produce actual canvas coordinates for the circle centres, and draw them with that information:

Try it here:

```js
function triangleCoordinates(n) {
    const result = [];
    let y = 0, 
        startX = 0;    
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i - startX > y) {
            startX = i;
            y++;
        }
        result.push([i - startX, y]);
    }
    return result;
}

function drawCircle(ctx, x, y, radius) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke(); 
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    RADIUS = 7,
    PADDING = 1;

inputCount.oninput = function () {    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (const [x, y] of triangleCoordinates(+this.value)) {
        drawCircle(ctx, (x*2+1)*(RADIUS+PADDING), (y*2+1)*(RADIUS+PADDING), RADIUS);
    }
}
```

```html
Number of circles: <input id="inputCount"><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function draw(max){
  let y = 0, x= 0, perRow = 1;
  while(max--){
    if(x >= perRow){
     y++; perRow++; x = 0;
    }
    drawCircle(x,y);
    x++
  }
}
```

Whenever the user inputs a number, call draw and define a function drawCircle that draws a circle at (x|y)

Comment: Thanks alot! Gonna try this out as soon as possible! :)